# Want to replace the words with space in multiple files using SED commmand

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Want to replace the words with space in multiple files using SED commmand

I have a word as 'Danny' with single quotes in many of my files in multiple directories which I want to change to 'Danny Samuel'

since I have a space in the new word this command wont work

```
find . -type f -exec sed -e 's/'Danny'/'Danny Samuel'/g' -i.php '{}' +
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from the replacement string.

Comment: If you need to quote the replacement and pattern, use a different set of quotes for the `sed` expression.

Comment: i tried this but doesnt work either find . -type f -exec sed -e 's/Danny/Danny Samuel/g' '{}' +

Comment: Could you elaborate _does not work_?

Comment: It doesnot change the Danny to Danny Samuel at all ....I checked the files it still says as Danny itself

Comment: @Danny, note that the `.php` files are the backup files (the original) the modified ones are the files themselves.

Comment: Thanks I know that since I am experimenting I already have taken the backup so I simply dont want the file.php to be backed up as file.php.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a single quote inside single quotes, the `'` in `'Danny` closes the quotes.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -e 's/'Danny'/'Danny Samuel'/g' -i.php '{}' +
                             ^^ !!!!! ^ !!!!!!!!!!!! ^^
                         quoted     quoted         quoted  
                              unquoted    unquoted
```

Write it:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.php -e "s/'Danny'/'Danny Samuel'/g" {} +
```

(note that `.php` is quite unexpected as an extension for backup files).

Comment: it goes on a loop if I remove the -i.php where as I can still execute the same command and remove the created backup files like file.php.php by this command "find . -name "*.php.php*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf"

Comment: @danny, use `-i` (GNU `sed`) or `-i ''` (FreeBSD, OS/X) if you want in-place editing but no backup.